# Hex to Binary Conversion in C showing wrong output

Tags: c, binary, hex

I'm trying to convert a 64bit plain hex text into binary. You can see in the below code I have assigned `plain_Text64` and `binary_Plain_Text64` as global variables. But after the execution of the function `hexToBin` the value of `binary_Plain_Text64` should be the new binary value of the given 64bit plain text. Unfortunately I'm getting some other. I have printed the value of `binary_Plain_Text64` in the `hexToBin` function itself and it works perfect. Can anyone help me?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int * hexToBin(char plain_Text64[]);


char plain_Text64[17]={};
int binary_Plain_Text64[64]={};

int main(){
  int *bin;
  printf("Enter 64bit Plain Text\n");
  scanf("%s",plain_Text64);
  bin=hexToBin(plain_Text64);
  int i=0;
  for(i=0;i<64;i++){
    //printf("%d\n",*(bin+i));
  }
 printf("%d\n",binary_Plain_Text64[0]);

}
//Hex Value to Binary
int * hexToBin(char plain_Text64[]){
  int k;
  int hexDigitToBinary[16][4] = {{0,0,0,0}, {0,0,0,1}, {0,0,1,0}, {0,0,1,1}, {0,1,0,0}, {0,1,0,1},
  {0,1,1,0}, {0,1,1,1}, {1,0,0,0}, {1,0,0,1}, {1,0,1,0}, {1,0,1,1}, {1,1,0,0}, {1,1,0,1}, {1,1,1,0}, {1,1,1,1}};
  char hexDigits[16] = {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8',
   '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'};
   char hexadecimal[17]={};
   int i,j,index=0;
   strcat(hexadecimal,plain_Text64);
   for(i=0; i<16; i++){
      for(j = 0; j < 16; j++){
        //printf("%c\t",hexadecimal[i]);
        //printf("%c\n",hexDigits[j]);
          if(hexadecimal[i] == hexDigits[j]){
            //printf("OK\n");
            for(k=0;k<4;k++){
              binary_Plain_Text64[index++]= hexDigitToBinary[j][k];
            }
          }
      }
    }
    return binary_Plain_Text64;
 }
```

Comment: To store all the 16 hex-digits in `plain_Text64[]`, you shall allocate at least 16+1 (for the NUL end of string) ==> `plain_Text64[17]` otherwise, you will have problem when `strcat(hexadecimal,plain_Text64);`. Please replace `strcat(hexadecimal,plain_Text64);` by `strcpy(hexadecimal,plain_Text64);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overwriting the same 4 elements of the target array each time in

```
binary_Plain_Text64[k] = hexDigitToBinary[j][k];
```

I suggest using a separate indexing variable which you increment after each use, such as

```
int index = 0;
// ...
binary_Plain_Text64[index++] = hexDigitToBinary[j][k];
```

Also as commented by @J.Piquard one array is too short for its input, since there is no room for string terminator

```
char plain_Text64[16]={};
```

Don't be mean with your user input string allocations, and try to limit their entry too.